# How to select duplicates to get proper results?

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

Could you please help me to write working sql query?

I need to select all duplicate link_rewrite. 
It's duplicate only if the id_shop, id_lang are the same.

See full code: https://github.com/Ha99y/prestashopCleanURLs/blob/master/PS15/cleanurls.php#L49

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id_product  |  id_shop  |  id_lang  |  link_rewrite |
-------------------------------------------------------
|     1       |    1      |     1     |   ipod-nano   |
|     1       |    1      |     2     |   ipod-nano   |
|     2       |    1      |     1     |   ipod-nano   |
|     2       |    1      |     2     |   ipod-nano   |
|     8       |    2      |     1     |   ipod-nano   |
|     8       |    2      |     2     |   ipod-nano   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `ps_product_lang`
WHERE `link_rewrite`
IN (SELECT `link_rewrite` FROM `ps_product_lang`
GROUP BY `link_rewrite`, `id_lang`
HAVING count(`link_rewrite`) > 1)
```

.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like the only thing missing in your query is the `id_shop` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `ps_product_lang`
WHERE `link_rewrite`
IN (SELECT `link_rewrite` FROM `ps_product_lang`
GROUP BY `link_rewrite`, `id_lang`, `id_shop`
HAVING COUNT(`link_rewrite`) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stated requirement is " It's duplicate only if the id_shop, id_lang are the same".  That means, somewhere, your query needs to contain something like this:

```
select id_shop, id_lang, count(*) records
from the applicable tables
group by id_shop, id_lang
having count(*) > 1
```

You just have to find the right spot to put that.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this in MySQL is to use `exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ps_product_lang` pl
WHERE exists (select 1 
              from `ps_product_lang` pl2
              where pl2.id_shop = pl.id_shop and
                    pl2.id_lang = pl.id_lang and
                    pl2.id_product <> pl.id_product
             );
```